# Have variable buttons in table referencing SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

So a little background, I have a table created, and would like to have this table be scale-able (i.e. have more rows added to it in the future through UI). The PHP below pulls data from an SQL database I have and displays it as a formatted table.

See comments in code and tl;dr at the bottom for an explanation of the issue.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM Main ORDER BY Room";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //columns
    echo "<table><tr>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Ready Since:</th>
        <th>Change Status</th>
        </tr>";
    //output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $room = $row["Room"];

        /*This is the problematic code here. I want this php to link to the form created below.
        The forms generate their own name according to the room number, and I want this $_POST
        to reference those varying room numbers. The submit button works a step late, i.e. 
        each time I press the button, it changes the date value for the LAST BUTTON PRESSED. Ex. if
        I press "submit" for the 2nd row, then press "submit" for the 3rd row, the 2nd row will 
        update. I've tried moving this if statement around the code thinking it may be a 
       chronological issue, but sadly this didn't work.*/ 

        if (isset($_POST[$room])) {

        //Update ReadyTime to time of button press (UTC - 6 hours for Mountain Time)
        $sql2 = "UPDATE Main SET Status='Waiting', ReadyTime=TIME_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(LOCALTIME(), INTERVAL -6 HOUR), '%r') WHERE Room='".$room."'";

        //update record
        $conn->query($sql2);

        //close
        $conn->close();
    }

     //echo records corresponding to columns
     echo "<tr>
              <td>".$row["Room"]."</td>
              <td>".$row["Status"]. "</td>
              <td>".$row["ReadyTime"]."</td>

     //the form in question
              <td><form method='post' id='form1'><button type='submit' name=". $room . " ID='status' form='form1'>Notify Dentist</button></form></td>
              </tr>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
};
```

tl;dr I have an SQL table displayed through PHP that I want to add to, but am having a hard time creating submit buttons with corresponding forms, which will have variable, numeric names in the future.

PS. If you mark as duplicate, please make sure the linked duplicate question is actually related, and not just of the same sub-genre. This is a messy question so feel free to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to get an array of the values already in the SQL table, modify the table based on which of the corresponding buttons was pressed, THEN get the results. The reason I was getting an error above was because I was retrieving the SQL table BEFORE I modified the table, so the table was always a step behind.

```
//if notify is pressed
foreach ($rooms as $i) {
    if (isset($_POST['waiting' . $i])) {
        //Update ReadyTime to time of button press (UTC - 6 hours for Mountain Time)
        $sql2 = "UPDATE Main SET Status='Waiting', ReadyTime=TIME_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(LOCALTIME(), INTERVAL -6 HOUR), '%r') WHERE Room='" . $i . "'";

        //update record
        $conn->query($sql2);

        //send text
        $body = 'Room '.$i.' is ready!';
        $text($body);
    }
}

//get sql results (after changes)
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >= 1) {
    //columns
    echo "<table><tr>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Ready Since:</th>
        <th>Notify</th>
        <th>Clear Time</th>
        <th>Delete Room</th>
        </tr>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr>
              <td>" . $row["Room"] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row["Status"] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row["ReadyTime"] . "</td>
              <td><form method='post' id='form1'><button type='submit' name=waiting" . $row["Room"] . " ID='status' form='form1'>Notify Dentist</button></form></td>
              <td><form method='post' id='form2'><button type='submit' name=clear" . $row["Room"] . " ID='status' form='form2'>Clear</button></form></td>
              <td><form method='post' id='form3'><button type='submit' name=delete" . $row["Room"] . " ID='delete' form='form2'>Delete</button></form></td>
              </tr>";
        array_push($rooms, $row["Room"]);
    }
    }
```